# Angular - How to apply is-open attribute properly on angular ui accordion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have an specific function which is working specially when you click any of the panels on the accordion. Now, the reason why I am here is because right now the function triggers once you click to open or to close the panels, and I don't want that, I want that function working only when you click the panels in order for them to be open. I saw that I can achieve it with something called `is-open` but actually I don't have an idea how to use it.

This the function I just mention:

```
$scope.addSportToLines = function(sportObj) {
  sportObj.shown = !sportObj.shown;
  var firstLeagues = _.first(sportObj.leagues);
  if (sportObj.shown || !firstLeagues) {
    loaderAlert.show();
    $scope.lineSport = sportObj;
    $scope.lineLeagues = [];
    $scope.deactivateLeagues();
    $scope.addLeagueToLines(firstLeagues);
  }else {
    $scope.defaultLines();
  }
};
```

And this is the accordion html:

```
    <accordion close-others="false">
      <accordion-group ng-repeat="sport in sports"
        ng-show="sport.leagues.length"
        ng-click="addSportToLines(sport);">
        <accordion-heading>
          <div>
            {{::sport.name}}
          </div>
        </accordion-heading>
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item"
            ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues"
            ng-class="{active: league.active}"
            ng-click="addLeagueToLines(league)">{{::league.name}}
          </a>
        </div>
      </accordion-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An accordian-group can have an is-open expression bound like this

```
      <accordian-group  is-open="myvar">
```

In your ng-click you can check to see if the value is set to true and don't do whatever it is you don't want done. Since it appears you are creating dynamic accordian groups you will have to pass in some unique identifier for "sport" into an is-open function and set/check that value for each one. Something like this:

```
     <accordian-group is-open="accordianStatus[sport.name])">

     $scope.accordianStatus = {}; // Map of which sports are open
```

Likewise you will have to set the flag to false when the item is closed.
Then use

```
     $scope.addSportToLines = function(sportObj) {
        if($scope.accordianStatus[sportObj.name]) {   // Already open check

        .......
```

Comment: I will try it this Monday at my job, in case that I need any help, I'll let you know my friend, thanks.